# Laravel - Redirect back with location

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

So in my footer I have a form for adding subscribers to a newsletter. When you enter your email and submit the form, you get redirected back with a message. Everything works fine. However the footer is at the bottom of the page and I get redirected back to the top. Is there a way to redirect and go to the footer directly? Here is the code in my controller:

```
public function addSubscriber(Request $request)
{
   $this->validate($request, [
       'email' => 'required|email'
   ]);

   ...code...

   return redirect()->back()->with(['added' => $message]);
}
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of doing `back()`, you could try something like this:

```
return redirect(url()->previous().'#subscribe');
```

Here `url()->previous()` will generate URL of previous page. So, you'll just need to add `#subscribe` which will scroll page down to an anchor. So no JS required.

Of course, you'll need to add a HTML anchor:

```
<a name="subscribe">Subscribe</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this:

1. Make a url like https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#introduction, and manage the scrolling of web page by #introduction. [Demo](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#introduction)
2. On success of message call a js function that scroll down your web page to certain pixel of height so that your footer is visible.